# Can't Install Pytorch Lightning Flash on Google Colab

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Pytorch Lighting Flash sounds really promising to me. I am trying to run the most basic tutorials on https://lightning-flash.readthedocs.io/ but I can't get them to run.

For example I am using the install instructions here https://lightning-flash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html to run this object detection sample here https://lightning-flash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/object_detection.html.

I have tried a few ways to install but none of them are working. For example:

`pip install 'lightning-flash[image]'`

That seems to work without any errors. Then I import the modules

```
import flash
from flash.core.data.utils import download_data
from flash.image import ObjectDetectionData, ObjectDetector
```

There is a reg squiggle under the flash so it looks like something is wrong. When I run the block I get these errors.

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchtext/_torchtext.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at6detail10noopDeleteEPv
```

Answer (score 0):

The good people in the Pytorch Lighting Flash community helped tweak the installation commands to get this working. I opened a bug with the details here https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/lightning-flash/issues/803

Installing these packages in this order works:

```
!pip install torch==1.8.1+cu102 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
!pip install icevision #==0.9.0a1
!pip install effdet 
!pip install lightning-flash[image]
!pip install git+https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/lightning-flash.git
!pip install torchtext==0.9.1
!pip uninstall fastai -y
#There is a bug in the latest release of icevision. Manually apply the fix.
!curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/airctic/icevision/944b47c5694243ba3f3c8c11a6ef56f05fb111eb/icevision/core/record_components.py --output /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/icevision/core/record_components.py
#Restart the kernel
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't import flash. import flash yields:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:11: UserWarning: Failed to load image Python extension: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torchvision/image.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK3c106IValue23reportToTensorTypeErrorEv
  warn(f"Failed to load image Python extension: {e}")